# How to round to the nearest decimals in a paragraph?

Tags: javascript, html, css

For example I have:

```
<p id = 'myp'>
I brought it for 2.545
I sold it for 1.245
I returned it for 5.4099
<p/>
<p id = 'myresult'> <p/>
```

Answer should be:

```
I brought it for 2.5
I sold it for 1.2
I returned it for 5.4
```

Keep the words in the paragraph while rounding the numbers.

```
    myp.toFixed(2); 
    myparagraph = document.getElementByid('myp');
    myparagraph.toFixed(2);
```

Doesn't work for my paragraph. I also tried MathRound(2); and other methods but it doesn't work. I'm still new to Javascript so I don't know what I'm doing. It is giving uncaught type error. I need to keep it in the paragraph I can't do var number1-1000 1000 times.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you show more code with exactly how you are trying to call this? Right now, it's just a blob of code. You say it's not working, but are you getting any errors in the console? We need a little more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) is a method of Number variables, so you need to get the numbers first. Also, rounding to one decimal point needs `.toFixed(1)`, not `.toFixed(2)`.

You can do something like this:

```js
const mypEl = document.getElementById('myp');
const myresultEl = document.getElementById('myresult');
const values = mypEl.innerHTML.split(/\s/g).filter(Boolean);
values.forEach(value => {
  myresultEl.innerHTML += Number(value).toFixed(1) + '\n';
});
```

```html
<p id='myp'>
  2.545
  1.245
  5.4099
</p>
<p id='myresult'>
</p>
```

Comment: Can you do it with words mixed in the paragraph? Because I have lots of words mixed with decimals so I need it to be rounded to 2 decimal places while keeping the words.

Comment: In that case, you might want to create separate `span`s for the numbers.

Comment: Can you explain what EL mean? and why is there => {. I don't understand filter(Boolean)

Comment: el means element, it's just naming I used. `=> {` is an arrow function. similar to `function() {`. `filter(Boolean)` is same is `filter(item => Boolean(item))` meaning, if there is any item that's `null`, `undefined` or `false`, it filters it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try splitting the content of #myp by the /n (new line character) then loop through the results, validate each item is an integer, convert to number then round down.

This is my thought process,  I'll try writing a code sample when i get to my pc .